# Approach on generating sorted html/php pages

Tags: php, html

So imagine you have online book store with a page that is a grid with 9 elements that represent book covers. Every book has a price, and when user load's page 1st time grid is generated in order that books are stored in database. Now, user has option to select option that is gonna load a grid that is in order (desc/asc). Now what is the best way to achieve this. This is what I've tried :

1) Easiest way is to make php page that is in order and simply put a link to that page in . Now this is easy, but if I had 30 different type of orders (price, popularity, year etc..) I would have to make whole bunch of sites.

2) I tried ajax : when user hits button I send data(how to order) to special php script that based on that data will create database query and I would then use php file manipulation to rewrite entire front page with new order , and I would simply echo that site and in ajax succes function I would do window.location.replace(sent_from_php) and that would load same site but since I changed its content it would now be in order. What wrong here is that when 1 user requests ordered site, second user will also see ordered site , not the original site.

So, how can I use my second approach, but in the way I isolate users . Users wants ordered site, php rewrites front page html and outputs new site. Second users gets a regular site (he doesen't get ordered site) and so on. Basically I need to isolate users, so changes one users makes to the site is not visible to any other user?

My index.php:

```
<?php
include 'db_menager.php';

$db_handler = new DB();
$query = "SELECT `Title`, `Autor`, `Price`, `Cover`, `Brief_desc`, `id` FROM `book` ORDER BY Price DESC";
$row = array();
$rows = $db_handler->select($query);

if ($rows)
    {
    echo "<ul id='main'>";
    while ($row = $rows->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
        echo '<li>  <img src = "' . $row["Cover"] . '"/>';
        echo '<p>Title : ' . $row["Title"] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Autor : ' . $row["Autor"] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Price : ' . $row["Price"] . '</p>';
        echo '</li>';
        }

    echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: how users see the same page? thats not normal. How are you handling the page generation? How to do that? Just have one method that needs sort variable and switch on it by `switch` statement, and order them after getting from db

Comment: I have index.php page that is main page that shows books in order they are stored in db. I have handle_ajax.php that based on sent data creates a query and puts a string in index.php. That string is all same code as in index.php  except that database query. That is how I sorted page. But the problem is, when another user requests index.php after that, ordered page is gonna get loaded

Comment: O_x nice architecture xd (no, its bad) you shouldnt change php contents from scripts. Can you show us some code from index.php?

Comment: data is from db, I know my architecture sucks, that is why am asking what is the standard way in making site's that have options to sort data in different ways

Comment: this is the main script : http://pastebin.com/jetUpjaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont ever modify php scripts from other files - thats a bad idea.
There are better solutions - Fortunately the simple ones.
Just get what user need from URL string. The queries are in the `$_GET` global array.

```
//default sort values
$sortby = "Price";
$order = "DESC";
if(isset($_GET['sortby'])){ //if theres a sortby query in the URL
    $sortby = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sortby']);
}
if(isset($_GET['order'])){ //if user provided elements order in the URL
    $order = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['order']);
    if($order == "DESC"){
        $order = "DESC";
    }else{
        $order = "ASC";
    }
}


$db_handler = new DB();
$query = "SELECT `Title`, `Autor`, `Price`, `Cover`, `Brief_desc`, `id` FROM `book` ORDER BY $sortby $order";
```

One note for this example: **ALWAYS USE ESCAPING**! (The mysqli_real_escape_string is better, but requires mysqli link (reference to your db, i dont have one and i dont know what methods,variables your DB class provides)).
**They are preventing you from [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**

Links will be

```
<a href="index.php?sort=Price&order=ASC">Sort from least exspensive</a> 
<a href="index.php?sort=Price&order=DESC">Sort from most exspensive</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time and helping me.

Comment: You're welcome. We are here to help others : )